# Redmine - Ruby on Rails - Populate "Custom Field" list data type with values from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, redmine

I am working on an Redmine web application. I would like to create a "Custom field", with data type of "List".

Currently, Redmine allows you to define the values in this list by typing them manually. However, in my case, I would like to know if there's a way I could populate the values in the list by defining an SQL `select` query so whatever is returned is in the values for that list. Perhaps a plugin that I could write?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As of now redmine doesn't have the feature you have to create plugin for this

Comment: Thank you for your comment, John. Could you please give an idea how to approach this solution?

Comment: Hi @callMeJava , did you solve your issue ? I have the same requirement so I'll be glad to know if you solved this.